# Django: Reverse lookup with no parameters?

Tags: python, regex, django, templates

In my template I've got this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'webapps:ajax-test' webapp.slug %}"
    ...
```

(note that the value of webapp.slug is 'ajax-test')

And my urls.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^ajax/(?P<pk>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$', views.ajax_test, name='ajax-test')
```

Which works fine, but if I try to do this without a param like this:

```
url(r'^ajax/ajax-test/$', views.ajax_test, name='ajax-test')
```

I get a NoReverseMatch error. In this situation, I don't need a  param because each ajax view is going to be a standalone view. Is there a cleaner way to do this without putting in a 'dummy'  param?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, simple solution, I need to not pass a param in my url template tag like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'webapps:ajax-test' %}"
    ...
```

Duh.